# how to put row onto another one? / CSS

Tags: html, css

on the image as you can see 'Sezon' and 'Poza sezonem' blocks are on another blocks(ND-CZW, PT-SB)

I'm trying to write html code of this image. how can I put Sezon,poza sezonem blocks on the blocks below?

```
<div class="parent">
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;background-color: #E96165;color: #fff">Ilosc 
gosci</td>
<td class="baslik1">Sezon</td> 
<td class="baslik1">Poza sezonem</td>
<td class="baslik1">Poza sezonem 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="baslik2"> </td>
<td class="baslik2">ND-CZW</td> 
<td class="baslik2">PT-SB</td>
<td class="baslik2">ND-CZW</td>
</tr>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you attach the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Flexbox with absolute positioning like this:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  background: lightgrey;
}

.table:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
}
.table:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 3;
}

.table > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
}

.cell {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.cell--head {
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.cell--logo {
  background-color: #E96165;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cell--head > div {
  padding-top: 30px;  
}

.cell > div {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.cell > div:first-of-type {
  border-left: 0;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  left: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="cell cell--logo">
      Ilosc gosci
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Ilosc gosci
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="cell cell--head">
      <span class="label">Sezon</span>
      <div>ND-CZW</div>
      <div>ND-CZW</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div>245 pln</div>
      <div>245 pln</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="cell cell--head">
      <span class="label">Poza sezonem</span>
      <div>ND-CZW</div>
      <div>ND-CZW</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div>245 pln</div>
      <div>245 pln</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <td class="baslik2"></td>
    <td class="baslik2"></td> 
    <td class="baslik2"></td>
    <td class="baslik2"></td>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have some wrong syntax, I tried achieve the same in the fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/Parthoghsh820/akhwgg2f/3/

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr class="header">
        <th colspan="2">
       <span>Major 1</span>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2">
        <span>Major 2</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subheader">
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```